# Include HTML inside partial and inside function

Tags: php, function, include

I am creating some widget for Word Press, but maybe this is standard PHP question, because it is related to some MVC pattern. I have some HTML that i need to output on page but that HTML is for now i inside function, i would like to transfer it to partial, because in the future there can be lots of more HTML, and if I make it like this it will be lots of spaghetti code.Here is what i have for now

```
class motractrucks extends WP_Widget{
  function widget($args, $instance, $defaults){
  echo '<p>'.$value1.'<p>'; 
  echo '<p>'.$value2.'<p>'; 
  echo '<p>'.$value3.'<p>'; 
  echo '<p>'.$value4.'<p>'; 
  echo '<p>'.$value5.'<p>'; 
  echo '<p>'.$value6.'<p>';
 }
}
```

This is just simple example, I have modified function easy that you can understand what i need, i was thinking to do something like, but how to pass values form inside function in that view?

```
class motractrucks extends WP_Widget{
  function widget($args, $instance, $defaults){
   include 'partials/userValues.php';
 }
}
```

And pass all values to that partial, any good idea and best code practice will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The part of this question that specifically pertains to PHP is the [variable scope](http://php.net/language.variables.scope). PHP functions have a local scope. So variables used inside those functions are considered to be local variables by default. Unless you explicitly import a variable from the global scope into the function's local scope via the `global` keyword, it's local. In your examples those variables are all undefined.

Also, using `echo` inside a function is never considered good practice, but I can't speak specifically to the WordPress aspect of your code as I'm not that familiar with WordPress.

Functions *should* take inputs as arguments and *should* return values as output. That's typically what you would consider *good* practice.

```
function foo($var1, $var2, $var3) {
    return <<<HTML
        <p>$var1</p>
        <p>$var2</p>
        <p>$var3</p>
HTML;
}
```

As far as including files for use in templates, that's usually fine in PHP. When you're doing those includes inside of a function it becomes easier to contain their scope, because `include` takes scope into account.

Let's say your `partials/userValues.php` file looks something like this...

```
    <p><?=$var1?></p>
    <p><?=$var2?></p>
    <p><?=$var3?></p>
```

If you want to include it from your function you can. You can also use output buffering with functions like [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob-start) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob-start) to write the output into a buffer and return that from the function instead of just printing directly to standard out.

```
function foo($var1, $var2, $var3) {
    ob_start(); // start the output buffer first
    include 'partials/userValues.php'; // include inherits the variable scope
    $output = ob_get_clean(); // close the buffer and store it in $output
    return $output; // return it to the caller
}
```